# Make associative array of unique values from column containing arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique, array-column

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21153
        [genre] => ["History","Drama", "Thriller"]
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21152
        [genre] => ["ACTION"]
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21151
        [genre] => ["ROMANTIC"]
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21150
        [genre] => ["Drama"]
    )

)
```

I have with the above array and I want to convert that array to an unique array as mentioned below, and there should be any duplicate values.

```
Array(
    [History] => "History"
    [ACTION] => "ACTION"
    [ROMANTIC] => "ROMANTIC"
    [Drama] => "Drama"
    [Thriller]=>"Thriller"
)
```

Comment: what have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: _"and there should be any duplicate values"_ - which duplicate values do you want?

Comment: What's the point of having an index similar to the value ?

Comment: the format of this `[genre] => ["History","Drama", "Thriller"]` makes me stumble. Is this the output of a `print_r()`?? What datatype is 'genre'? To achieve this output via `print_r` it would have to be the literal string `["History","Drama", Thriller"]`

Comment: "and there should be any duplicate values"- Sorry my mistake, we shouldn't allow any duplicate key and value pair

Comment: Yes, it is print_r() type

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get how the resulting array makes any sense, but here you are:
Loop through the array, loop through the genres and push items to a new array.

```
<?
$a = Array
(
    [
        "id" => 21153,
        "genre" => ["History","Drama", "Thriller"]
    ],

    [        
        "id" => 21152,
        "genre" => ["ACTION"]
    ]

);


$result = [];
foreach($a as $b) {
    foreach($b['genre'] as $genre) {
        $result[$genre] = $genre;  // don't need to check if it exists already, because we'll overwrite it anyway.
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

// output:
Array
(
    [History] => History
    [Drama] => Drama
    [Thriller] => Thriller
    [ACTION] => ACTION
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using foreach() loop and in_array() function like below

```
$myArray=array();
$array = array(
            array("id"=>21153,"genre"=>array("History","Drama", "Thriller")),
            array("id"=>21152,"genre"=>array("ACTION")),
            array("id"=>21151,"genre"=>array("ROMANTIC")),
            array("id"=>21150,"genre"=>array("Drama"))          
        );

foreach($array as $arr){    
    foreach($arr as $genres){
        if(is_array($genres)){
            foreach($genres as $elem){
                  if (!in_array($elem, $myArray))
                  {
                    $myArray[$elem]=$elem;
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that resolves what you ask, though I'm not sure it is quite useful to have value and key being identical. I'm just looping over all genders and add only the ones I don't already have store in returning array. probably a bit dangerous with your code because it is case sensitive

```
function getGenders(array $rawValues) :array {
    $distinctGenders = [];
    foreach ($rawValues as $row) {
        foreach ($row["genre"] as $gender) {
            if (!in_array($gender, $distinctGenders)) {
                $distinctGenders[$gender] = $gender;
            }
        }
    }

    return $distinctGenders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing the changes, I have fixed this,

```
$responseData = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21153
        [genre] => ["History","Drama", "Thriller"]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21152
        [genre] => ["ACTION"]
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21151
        [genre] => ["ROMANTIC"]
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21150
        [genre] => ["Drama"]
    )

       foreach ($responseData as $data){
       $strReplace = str_replace(array('[',']') , ''  ,  $data['genre']);
       $explodeData[] = explode(',', $strReplace);  
   }
```

And the output after exploding is :

```
$explodeData = Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "History"
            [1] => "Drama"
            [2] => "Thriller"
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "ACTION"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => "ROMANTIC"
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => "Drama"
    )
```

)

And finally by the foreach loop :

```
       foreach ($explodeData as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $genres) {
            if (!in_array($genres, $myArray)) {
                $myArray[$genres] = $genres;
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally the required output comes as below :

```
Array(
["History"] => "History"
["Drama"] => "Drama"
["Thriller"] => "Thriller"
["ACTION"] => "ACTION"
["ROMANTIC"] => "ROMANTIC"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten the column of data.
2. Assign keys from the values (this ensures uniqueness).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fkvo8))

```
$array = [
    ["id" => 21153, "genre" => ["History", "Drama", "Thriller"]],
    ["id" => 21152, "genre" => ["ACTION"]],
    ["id" => 21151, "genre" => ["ROMANTIC"]],
    ["id" => 21150, "genre" => ["Drama"]]         
];

$flat = array_merge(...array_column($array, 'genre'));
var_export(
    array_combine($flat, $flat)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'History' => 'History',
  'Drama' => 'Drama',
  'Thriller' => 'Thriller',
  'ACTION' => 'ACTION',
  'ROMANTIC' => 'ROMANTIC',
)
```